# How can I have Sleep Focus stay on longer tonight?

Tags: sleep-wake, alarm, focus

Last night, I worked late and wanted to push back my usual Sleep Focus end time from 7:00 to 9:00am. It looked like I was allowed to do that:

[image]

However, at 7:30am I was awakened by an email. Despite my Sleep Focus showing that it would stay on until 9, the Focus part didn’t actually stay engaged:

[image]

Is there no way to have the Sleep Focus last longer for one night?

Comment: It should work the way you wanted it to. Do you have any other scheduled focuses?

Comment: I do have a work focus that starts at 9am every day. But in a normal day there is no focus between 7am and 9am. So the screenshot of the lack of any active focus was just how things looked at 7:30 this morning.

Comment: Hmm, this is an odd one - I regularly extend my sleep schedule as you described and it extends properly. Are you running a fully updated iOS?

Comment: 16.1.2. Looks like 16.2 is now available, and I will update. But I don’t see any relevant issue in the release notes so I am going to continue to be leery of trusting Sleep Focus for now. I’ll probably disable it for the night and use a custom Focus if I run into this issue in the future.

Comment: Also if you want to add your comment as an answer, I’ll be happy to accept it.

Comment: thanks for offering but i don't feel like I really solved your problem 

Comment: Well, there may be a bug or a user error. But it was unclear to me after looking at the Apple documentation what the process was even supposed to look like, and I think you answered that! So this way, when future people search, they’ll find your answer.

Comment: Thanks to your comments above, I think I figured out the issue! When you asked "Do you have any other scheduled focuses", I thought I only had a Work focus. But actually, I also had a legacy "Do not disturb" focus that was scheduled at the same time as my usual Sleep focus. So I am guessing that I pushed back my sleep focus end-time, but the Do Not Disturb end time arrived at 7, allowing notifications.

Comment: That was probably it - the different focuses interact with each other in sometimes unpredictable ways

Comment: Interestingly, it’s a weekend day when my sleep focus is scheduled to turn off at 9, my DND focus has been deleted, my work focus doesn’t turn on until Monday, and my sleep focus still turned off at 7. I have opened up a bug report with Apple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm that this feature is intended to work as you want it to. I frequently adjust my Sleep schedule and my focus appears to stay active until the later date for the night I change it.

It appears you might have encountered a bug.